# Is it possible to modify output of read event by other process?

Tags: read, events, lsm

I want to intercept event and then modify output. So main question not about how to get notification about event, but how to modify output.

**Example**

Content of `file.txt`

```
Current user is
```

When some app owned by user (or by user with group that have access) will try to read file, app will get modified (by listener process) content for example `Current user is name_of_user`

Comment: Your question is too broad ... What is an `event` ? Is there only one file or this operation may be done on several files ? Is there only one app for which this operation may be done or for every app on the system ? Is there a specific trigger for the modification ? Do you have root account  ?

Comment: Looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). So what is the real problem?